# menu gets full width. list items share equally width to get full width

Tags: html, list, css, responsive-design

I have an horizontal menu and i want it to get full width of my website but something is not right. My menu is looking like this right now and here is the code for it:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#" > <span class="link"> <span class="link"> HOME </span>  </span> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" > <span class="link"><span class="link"> ABOUT </span>  </span> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" >  <span class="link"> <span class="link">FAQ</span>  </span> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" > <span class="link"> <span class="link">CARS</span>  </span> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" > <span class="link"> <span class="link">CONTACT</span>  </span> </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

ul.menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:320px;
    top:30%;
    right:0%;
}
ul.menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    padding-top:30px;
}
ul.menu li {
    float:left;
    width:175px;
    height:85px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.menu li > a {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:175px;
    height:60px;
    z-index:12;
    background:transparent url(images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}
```

[image]

So, i now want to make this menu get full width of the site and make each list item share the full amount of width equally so each one of these boxes will stretch at the same amount to get the full width of the website. What i tried so far is to play with width, position, display but nothing worked. I set the width of ul.menu li to 100% and what i got was

[image]

and by setting the width of ul.menu li > a at 100% i get this

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the width of your `li` to 20% because you have 5 items and

```
100% / 5 = 20%
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2tmJn/)**

Answer (score 1):

Update the following two classes like below.

Instead of this

```
ul.menu li {
float:left;
width:175px;
height:85px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
 }
 ul.menu li > a {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:175px;
height:60px;
z-index:12;
background:transparent url(images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
 }
```

Use this

```
ul.menu li {
float:left;
width:20%;
height:85px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
 }
 ul.menu li > a {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:60px;
z-index:12;
background:transparent url(images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
 }
```